# cannot load simple csv file into tableau public 9.3

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I am trying to load the following simple csv file into tableau public 9.3:

```
customers,item1,item2,item3,item4
1,0,0,0,0
2,0,0,0,0
3,0,0,0,0
```

However, it doesn't read the file as separate columns, despite the field separator being Comma. Instead it treats the whole line as one column. Any help would be greatly appreciated :
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you change your locale settings to English US you will be able to load the file.  You should also be able to work around this by creating a schema.ini file.

Comment: I was stuck during so long time... I changed my locale setting from France to English UK !

Answer (score 3):

**Go to Data > Manage fields > [Field] Options**

You can also control imported CSV behavior post import both by splitting individual columns (which will remain split on update as well), or by the image below at the CSV level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That doesn`t work for me. So I reopen the .csv file in Excel and save it again in .csv format with ',' as the delimeter.

After that my file looks like .csv with ';' delimeter and works with Tableau.

Comment: You save it with "," and the now the delimeter is ";"? I don't understand.